# Asymptotic solution of the first order ODE $\dot x(t) = A(\epsilon t) x(t)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Let $x: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ be a vector-valued function, and let $A:\mathbb R \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a matrix-valued function. Assume that they are sufficiently regular. I am interested in the asymptotic expansion of the ODE
$$\dot x(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = A(\epsilon t) x(t), \quad \epsilon \to 0.$$
In general, if $A(t)$ and $A(s)$ does not commute, this ODE is hard to solve exactly. However, there is a hope to solve this ODE asymptotically, since $A(\epsilon t)$ is slowly varying. Considering that the solution is $x(t) = e^{At}x(0)$ if $A$ is constant, I expect that one could "patch" the solution for instantaneous $t$ appropriately.

Note that by rescaling $s=\epsilon t$, the ODE can be alternatively written as
$$\epsilon \frac{d\tilde x}{ds}(s) = A(s)\tilde x(s).$$
This reminds me of the WKB approximation, but I only know the WKB approximation for second order differential equation.

How can I obtain an asymptotic expansion of the solution of the ODE above?